# Retry failed xcodebuild test

Tags: bash, jenkins, xcodebuild

I am building custom Jenkins build script (sh) for iOS app build/test checks.
But sometimes UI test fails just because of timing issue, so I want it to re run few more times to make sure the issue is real.

```
for (( ATTEMPT=1; ATTEMPT<=2; ATTEMPT++ ))
do
      xcodebuild [flags] test #add_result_saving_mechanism

      #if failed, do smth to go to next attempt. Else - break
      if SOME_KIND_OF_FAIL_CHECK; then
         continue
      else
         break
      fi
fi
```

I used xcpretty before, so was able to read $PIPESTATUS and react accordingly, but xcpretty is crashing for `xcodebuild test` for some reason, so looking ways to do without it

```
xcodebuild [flags] test | xcpretty
STATUS="${PIPESTATUS}"
if [ "$STATUS" != "0" ]; then
      FAILURE_MSG="${TARGET} (${BUILD_NAME}) failed UI/Unit testing"
      #try next attempt if available
      continue
else
      break
fi
```

How can I handle these retries without pipes/xcpretty?

Comment: If one of the answers to your question is correct you should consider accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

From the jenkins perspective - it always used to bail early if a script encountered an error, so you could try this type of syntax to prevent that (in the jenkins config this is, not in the script itself)

```
jenkins_build_script.sh || true
# continue with things...
```

Also, if you're having trouble capturing the failure itself - try piping the xcodebuild output to a log file and then grep-ing for the errors you're anticipating.

Answer (score 0):

Since you said it's a script run by Jenkins you can handle the retry from Jenkins pipeline instead of inside the shell script.

As in the example from the docs

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Deploy') {
            steps {
                retry(3) {
                    sh './flakey-deploy.sh'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[You can read about it here](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/running-multiple-steps/)

Hope  this will help good luck.